# Use azure Blob storage from PCL with Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, storage, printer-control-language

I'm currently writing an app which will target multiple platforms thanks to xamarin.
The logic of the app in in a PCL and I'm using a WPF app as a frontend to test the PCL.
I need to connect to my BLOB storage account which works perfectly from the WPF app with the following code which resides in the PCL :

```
        bool connected = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!connected)   
        {
           try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CLIENT | Connecting to Storage try " + (attempts + 1).ToString());
                // Retrieve storage account from connection string.
                storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(TechnicalData._BLOBCONNECTIONSTRING);

                // Create the blob client.
                blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                // Retrieve a reference to a container. 
                blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(TechnicalData._BLOBCONTAINERFLIGHTLOGS);

                // Create the container if it doesn't already exist.
                blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

            connected = true;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                attempts++;
                connected = false;

            }
        }
```

However, when used from a WP8 app, the following error occurs :

CLIENT | Connecting to Storage try 21
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DLL
Could not load file or assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.ParseImpl(String connectionString, CloudStorageAccount& accountInformation, Action`1 error)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String connectionString)
   at APXClient.PCL.AirproxClient.ConnectBlobStorage()

Help would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: try to add reference to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DLL to your windows phone project too. check for it.

Comment: Thanks for your input loop, already tried that but it still doesn't work. However, a different exception is raised : A first chance exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in APXClient.PCL.DLL